# How to set BackColor of DataGridView when I know the row and column index of the cell to be colored?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backcolor

I'm allowing the user to search a DataGridView's cells for an entered search value and then I need to highlight all cells that match that search text.

I have the means to search through the DGV's DataTable for the cell with the search text, but, knowing the row and column index, I can't figure out how to set the BackColor for the desired cell.

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = txtSearchCatsGrid.Text;

    DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvCategories.DataSource);
    string cellValue;
    int rowIndex;
    int columnIndex;

    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; columnIndex++)
        {
            cellValue = dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString();

            if (searchText == cellValue)
            {
                // Set corresponding dgvCategories cell's background color to yellow
                dgvCategories.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption was I could just put "BackColor = Color.Yellow" at the end of that unfinished line in the if block, but obviously that won't work.

How do I color the cell when I know the row and column index?

Comment: `dgvCategories[columnIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;` Btw, you don't need a new DataTable, just `var dt = dgvCategories.DataSource as DataTable;`

Comment: @Jimi, thanks - that did it. I adjusted my code, as well, for the DataTable.

Comment: What happens when you sort a column ? Do the colors stick ? I would say no.

Comment: @Anonymous, it clears the backcolor when a column header is clicked to sort by that column, but for my needs that's fine.